# In the Azure Portal, what is the difference between Azure AD B2C & B2C Tenants

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

When I search for B2C in the azure portal, i get two items returned, Azure AD B2C & Azure AD Tenants (see screenshot below).

I do not understand why these things are separate, and cannot find documentation to explain what specific service each of these items provide.

Appreciate any expertise to explain the reason for the two services:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

B2C tenants lists the Azure AD B2C tenants linked to subscriptions in the currently active tenant for billing.

Azure AD B2C opens the AAD B2C management panel when you have the B2C tenant active in the portal.